# Excel Vba - Using an apostrophe in an sql string

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel, vba

I'm using excel to input data into an Access database and some of my data strings contain an apostrophe for measurements.

This is my SQL input string

```
    stSQL = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductUnit, SupplierID) " & _
            "Values ('" & cboxItemNum & "', '" & txtDescription & "', '" & txtUnit & "', " & linkPID & ")"

    cn.Execute (stSQL)
```

My string is as follows:

Aliplast 4E White. 30" X 80' X 1/4" Soft.

In this string the ' after the 80 is causing the error and I'm not sure how to get around this. I can't just tell the user not to enter an apostrophe. How can I get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can correct this either by using parameters (recommended) or by using Replace.

```
& Replace(txtDescription,"'","''") &
```

**Parameters**

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.command
cn.Open ServerConnect

cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

stSQL = "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, " _
   & "ProductDescription, ProductUnit, SupplierID) " _
   & "Values (param1,param2,param3,param4)"

cmd.CommandText = stSQL
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
With cmd
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
         "param1", adInteger, adParamInput, , cboxItemNum)
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
         "param2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, txtDescription )
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
         "param3", adInteger, adParamInput, , txtUnit )
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter( _
         "param4", adInteger, adParamInput, , linkPID )
End with
cmd.Execute recs
```

Note that while I have named these parameters param1 to param4, that is for my convenience, all that matters is the order, which must match the order in which the parameters are to be used.

Comment: Please use parameters, or google around about [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks for the help Remou! I'll switch everything to parameters today to avoid any future problems.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the apostrophe in values that are encased in single quotes (e.g. the O'Brien in 'O'Brien') as follows: O' & "'" & 'Brien

Use the following code snippet: Replace(rs![field1], " ' ", " ' " & " & " & """" & " ' " & """" & " & ' ") & "'" ). NOTE I have added a space between the single and double quotes to make it easier to tell them apart. In the actual code you use, you should not have these spaces.

For example

Instead of

Docmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO Tablename (DestinationField) SELECT '" & rs![field1] & "'")

use

Docmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO Tablename (DestinationField) SELECT '" & Replace(rs![field1], "'", "'" & " & " & """" & "'" & """" & " & '") & "'" )

This worked for me and allowed me to use VBA to insert values containing apostrophes (single quote marks) into a table using SQL insert statements